# after using where condition with parameter Css is not working in laravel

Tags: php, html, css, laravel, web-deployment

I am trying to list database details using where condition with parameter after calling this function CSS not working but all data is list down properly and without parameters, CSS working properly.

**web.php**

```
Route::get('/viwelist/{id}','Front\SISProfileController@check');
```

**controller**

```
class SISProfileController extends Controller
 {

 public function check($district){

    $list = SISAccount::all()->where('District', '==', $district);

    //dd($list->all());


    return view('Front.listSIS', compact('list'));

}

 }
```

**link**

```
 <a href="{{ URL('/viwelist/'.'districtname')}}">click</a>
```

[image: This is the viwe]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing is getting all the elements from the database and the checking that condition through `Collection::where` method, and this will cause a lot of problem if in the database there're a lot of data. Instead you should use the `where` method directly on the database, and than get back only those records, so you should do something like:

```
$list = SISAccount::where('District', '=', $district)->get(); //to get back a Collection with all the records

$list = SISAccount::where('District', '=', $district)->first(); //to get only the first record, like if District is your primary key
```

The css problem is probably caused by the fact that you have put a relative link on your header as position of the css file, instead you should have something like `/asset/css.css`, so with a `/` at the beginning

Comment: problem is in my CSS links I was cheng it like this and problem solved  `{{ Html::style('assets/css/bootstrap.min.css')}}`, anyway your answer is very helpful.

Comment: Perfect, set it as answer to close this question